# Ruby on Rails collection output in collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got this code:

```
    <%= collection_select :channel, @channelList, :id, :channelname, {prompt: (t "channel.add.prompt")}, class: "form-control"%>
```

And got this error:

[image]

Its a normal active relation

[image]

Whats my mistake in this case?

thanks

Comment: `@channelList ` what it contains ?

Comment: @RajarshiDas look at his last screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

You have to specify: `object, method, collection, value_method, text_method`, you probably forgot to set the `object` param.

Which would make this:

```
<%= collection_select :object, :channel, @channelList, :id, :channelname, {prompt: (t "channel.add.prompt")}, class: "form-control"%>
```

(replace `:object` with your object you want to save the channel to)

Comment: just want to print out those in the selection, later I want do some jquery magic ;)

Comment: Okay, no problem :)